# PHP generate a HTML page that contains a javascript, then include the resulting page into another php file

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to create a dynamic slideshow by using php to list all files from a folder.After getting all images, I complete a javascript code that requires the location of the pictures. The php file works ok.
The problem is that if i want to include the resulting php file inside another, my javascript is not executed.
What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code that generates the slideshow(slideshow.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">

    <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

    <title>Design Shack - Full Screen Wedding Slideshow</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="supersized.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/effects.core.js"></script>
    <script src="js/effects.slide.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="supersized.3.0.js"></script>

    <?php

    function numara_elemente_folder($directory)
{ 
//$directory = "/path/to/dir/";
static $filecount = 0;
$files = glob($directory . "*");
if ($files){
 $filecount = count($files);
}
return $filecount;
//echo $filecount; 
}



    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';  

        echo "
        $(function(){
            $.fn.supersized.options = {  
                startwidth: 1200,  
                startheight: 800,
                vertical_center: 1,
                slideshow: 1,
                navigation: 1,
                thumbnail_navigation: 1,
                transition: 1, //0-None, 1-Fade, 2-slide top, 3-slide right, 4-slide bottom, 5-slide left
                pause_hover: 0,
                slide_counter: 1,
                slide_captions: 1,
                slide_interval: 6000,
                slides : [ "."\r\n";

        $directorul_cu_poze='wallpapers_stalker/';
        //below line and commnent $images variable currently in use
        $images = glob($directorul_cu_poze."*");
        $nr_imagini=numara_elemente_folder($directorul_cu_poze);
        //Display image using foreach loop
        foreach($images as $key=>$image)
{
if ($key+1<$nr_imagini) 
{   
echo "{image : '".$image."'},"."\r\n";  
}
else
{
echo "{image : '".$image."'}"."\r\n";       
}   
}
echo "]";
echo "};";
echo "$('#supersized').supersized()"."\r\n"; 
echo        '});'."\r\n";
echo '</script>'."\r\n";
?>

    <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>

<body>

<!--Loading display while images load-->
<div id="loading">&nbsp;</div>

<div id="navBar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://designshack.co.uk/?p=15337">ShutterPics Photography</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://designshack.co.uk/?p=15337">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://designshack.co.uk/?p=15337">Wedding</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://designshack.co.uk/?p=15337">Engagement</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://designshack.co.uk/?p=15337">Family</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://designshack.co.uk/?p=15337">Prices</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://designshack.co.uk/?p=15337">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>

<!--Slides-->
<div id="supersized"></div>



<!--<div id="prevthumb"></div>
<div id="nextthumb"></div>


Control Bar
<div id="controls-wrapper">
    <div id="controls">

        <!--Slide counter--*>
        <div id="slidecounter">
            <span class="slidenumber"></span>/<span class="totalslides"></span>
        </div>

        <!--Slide captions displayed here--*>
        <div id="slidecaption"></div>

        <!--Navigation--*>
        <div id="navigation">
            <img id="prevslide" src="images/back_dull.png"/><img id="pauseplay" src="images/pause_dull.png"/><img id="nextslide" src="images/forward_dull.png"/>
        </div>

        <a href="http://www.buildinternet.com" class="stamp"><img src="images/supersized-logo.png"/></a>

    </div>
</div>-->


</body>
</html>
```

Here is the page that need to include the slideshow.php.I call it index.php:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<style>
contents {

    padding: 10px 40px; 
    background: #dddddd;
    width: 800px;
    height: auto;

}
<style>

    <div id="links" class="myCustom1">

    </div>

    <div id="contents" class="myCustom2">
        <?php include('slideshow.php'); ?>
    </div>

</body>
<html>
```

If i run the slideshow.php it works ok.
If i try to run index.php, the slideshow pictures are not visible.

Thank you!